# Pass an extra parameter that is not part of the model into the controller

Tags: razor, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the code below that shows my Create cshtml page and the controller connected to it.

It's working fine, however now I need to add another field to the form that is not in the GameManagement.Game model.

This field is called "CreatorUserId" and does not exist in the model I'm using.

But I do I get the value of this field, and then pass it into the controller when it's not part of the model?

Thanks!

Create.cshtml:

```
@model GameManagement.Game


<div>
    <div>
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div>
                <label asp-for="Id"></label>
                <input asp-for="Id" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label asp-for="Description"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label asp-for="DisplayName"></label>
                <input asp-for="DisplayName" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Creator User ID</label>
                <input id="CreatorUserId" />
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Description,DisplayName")] Game newGame)
{

     // code to send the form information (Id, Description, DisplayName) to a 3rd party API

     apiResult = await apiClient.createNewGame(
        newGame.Id,
        newGame.Description,
        newGame.DisplayName,
        // CreatorUserId ??  not in Game model....

     return View(apiResult);
}
```

Comment: you should create a new model (maybe call it `CreateGamePostModel`) which has all the same fields as Game plus CreatorUserId. Have the Create action use `CreateGamePostModel` as its only parameter).
Then, when you post, you can transfer all the required fields to Game and then do whatever you want with the CreatedUserId field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @johnluke.laue suggested , the best solution is to create a new view model to include the needed properties .

If you insist on not creating a new viewmodel , the workaround could be add name attribute :

```
<input id="CreatorUserId" name="CreatorUserId" />
```

And get value on server side like :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Description,DisplayName")] Game newGame, string CreatorUserId)
{
}
```